How do you end-punctuate quotes when the entire quote is used as a noun phrase?
How do you punctuate quotes when the entire quote is used as a noun phrase, especially as the subject of an independent clause, under conditions where no punctuation would usually be used for a noun or noun phrase?

1:  "This is properly punctuated" is a quote used as a subject.


2:  "This is properly punctuated," is a quote used as a subject.


3:  "This is properly punctuated." is a quote used as a subject.

Related but seeming to point in different directions (2 and 1): How to Punctuate Two Quoted Independent Clauses Within a Declarative Sentence, How to punctuate two quotes within a sentence.

In my experience, the standard U.S. convention on punctuating complete-sentence quotations within longer sentences that do not end with the quotation is in line with the examples in The Chicago Manual of Style, sixteenth edition (2010) at 13.14 ("Initial capital or lowercase—run-in quotations"), which actually appear in the context of a different issue (whether to initial-cap or lowercase the first letter of the quoted sentence when it isn't the first word in the overall sentence containing the quotation):

[relevant examples:]

As Franklin advised, "Plough deep while sluggards sleep."
His aphorism "Experience keeps a dear school, but fools will learn at no other" is a cogent warning to people of all ages.


As applied to the specific quotation in the posted question, Chicago's guidance would be to use neither a comma nor a period at the end of the embedded quotation:

"This is properly punctuated" is a quote used as a subject.

In UK style, The Oxford Guide to Style (2002) seems to reach a similar conclusion, although its relevant examples at 5.13.2 ("Relative placing with other punctuation") focus on whether to place end punctuation inside or outside the close quotation mark when the quotation appears at the end of the overall sentence:

When a sentence long quotation is used as an explanation or specimen, the full point [period] usually does not fall within the closing quotation mark:

Cogito ergo sum means 'I think, therefore I am'.
We need not 'follow a multitude to do evil'.
Lat A stand for 'There exists at least one tree in real space'.
He believed in the proverb 'Dead men tell no tales'.


The issue that Oxford examines here is not relevant to U.S. style because in U.S. style the period normally goes inside the close quotation mark whether the quoted language is a complete sentence or a fragment. Nevertheless, it appears from Oxford's "Cogito ergo sum" example, where the Latin sentence is set in italics but not otherwise punctuated, that Oxford would not have put a comma or a period after "sum" if it had chosen to set the embedded sentence in quotation marks instead of italicizing it.

It gets even trickier when one is quoting printed material verbatim and wishes to preserve punctuation.

I think most style guides on quotations are intended for when you're using it to represent reported speech/writing or referring to the meaning of the quoted material. Sven Yargs's answer has a number of examples of these, and those guidelines are appropriate in that context.
But I think that when you're using the quote to refer to literal text, I think it would be best to reproduce it verbatim, with only the original punctuation inside the quotes. For instance, if you want to make a statement about the number of punctuation characters in the quoted text, it wouldn't make sense to change the punctuation. This is obviously not correct:

"Declarative sentences should end with a period" ends with a period.


My first instinct is Chicago style:

"This is a sentence" is a sentence.

But then you're in pretty rare territory here. The point of style guidance is to try to get everyone on board about common usages, to facilitate more consistent reading due to the consensus. The point is not to try to cover every possible potential idiosyncrasy of language, only to make writing more universally comprehensible for most reading. In this case, the comma could go almost as well. The descriptivist solution would be to use what feels right, and try to be consistent within the publication. Even UChicago style has relented on this kind of point in recent years.
